# How to repopulate value in vector

Tags: c++

I set my vector size to 2 and trying to repopulate the input values after it reaches 2. but I have no idea how should I do it.

e.g

output

```
a
b
```

after I type in c it will output

```
c
b
```

and after I type d it will output

```
c
d
```

-

```
storeInfo.resize(2);//set the size
storeInfo.push_back(something);//put the value inside vector
//how to repopulate with values within the range after it reaches more than 2?

for(int i = 0; i< storeInfo.size(); i++) {
     cout << storeInfo[i];
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a deque? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/

Answer (score 1):

```
storeInfo.resize(2);
int curIdx = 0;

while(1) {
  ... <set val somehow> ...
  storeInfo[curIdx] = val;
  curIdx = (curIdx + 1) % 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you appear to be looking for is a FIFO (first in, first out) structure.  `std::deque` fits that mold (sort of), but would require some custom handling to do exactly what you want.

If you are willing/able to use Boost, it has a [circular buffer template](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html).

Alternatively, you could also use `std::array` if you know the size at compile time (again, it would require some custom handling to act like a ring/circular buffer.

Comment: With the deque, he'd just have to pop everytime he wants to push

Comment: @Pacane Which would mean he would have to either make sure he does the pop every time (poor design), or wrap it in a custom class to do it (better), but either way it is custom handling.  If he knows the buffer size at compile time, `std::array` would be more efficient in terms of memory usage.  But if he is willing to use the Boost libraries, the circular buffer template does exactly what he wants with an interface that is very similar to a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your code to these:

```
storeInfo.insert(storeInfo.begin(), something);
storeInfo.resize(2);


for(int i = 0; i< 2; i++) {
      cout << storeInfo[i];
}
```

Comment: He would either need to do the resize after every insert (poor design choice), or create a wrapper that does it after every insert (better, but there are still better approaches).